# Registering a Template within an intellij Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity, intellij-plugin

I have created my Apache Velocity template under `/resources/fileTemplates/internal/myTemplateClass.vm` and would like to use it through:

```
final JavaDirectoryServiceImpl javaDirectoryService = new JavaDirectoryServiceImpl();
javaDirectoryService.createClass(myPsiDirectory,
                                 "MyClassname",
                                 "myTemplateClass");
```

So I added the following in my plugin.xml:

```
  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <!-- Add your extensions here -->
    <internalFileTemplate name="myTemplateClass"/>
  </extensions>
```

However when I run my plugin it claims that it did not find a template with the name "myTemplateClass". I assume it is cause I haven't linked to the file perse. Where should I link this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `<internalFileTemplate>` with the name of "myTemplateClass" and you want to use it to create a Java class, the template needs to be stored as `fileTemplates/internal/myTemplateClass.java.ft`. So you need to change the extension of your file.

Comment: added the .java I still get Template not found: myTemplateClass  . Posibly need to pass something different to the createClass to match as well?

Comment: Nv mind. needed to be .ft    .vm was not recognised even if it's in the docs

Comment: I posted another question, maybe you know the answer. How can I pass variables to this template before generating